# How can I get this regex right?

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to split tokens with `@`, and well meanwhile not allowing specific characters. I came up with this

```
(@\w+[^ -+=(><)])
```

But it doesn't work precisely! Suppose our target string is this :

```
 (() >= @a -5 and () <= @7 and ()= @127 and () = @1-7 and ()= @name_asd ()= @'hey this is a string')
```

it doesn't get single character tokens, and also it seems to accept `-` as a valid character while it shouldn't! I also wanted to be able to parse and match strings like:

```
@'something arbitrary with'
```

as well, but couldn't figure it out so far.

### Update

I need to get the token with `@` altogether meaning I want

```
@a  For  () >= @a -5 
@7  For  () <= @7 
@127 For ()= @127
@1  For  () = @1-7  
@name_asd For  ()= @name_asd 
and 
@'hey this is a string' For ()= @'hey this is a string'
```

Comment: So what would be target *output* string?

Comment: just want to get the matching correct, the output is not important at the moment.

Comment: Without expected output how we answer this question?

Comment: I updated the question, to be more clear i need to tokenize the items with @. be it a character or a string  just like i gave an example above.

Comment: So `@1-7` you would need `1-7` not just `1`?

Comment: Simply something like `@([^'][^ +=(><)-]*|'[^']*')`? (I'm sure it can be done better, hence the comment instead of an answer)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksoon: Yes thats exactly it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See demo:

```
@(?:\w+|'[^']*')
```

Also place your `-` at the end to avoid forming an unwanted range. See demo:

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/87

It wasn't getting `single character tokens` because you have a space after single character and you have not allowed a space after `\w+`.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question, this is not actually what i intended, I need to match the string altogether with the @ sign

Comment: Thanks, but it doesnt catch the @1-7 part (should get @1 in this part), and it does'nt catch the last part either (enclosed in ' this is a...')

Comment: Thanks, but doesnt get the last part

Answer (score 1):

Here, try this:

```
(@[\w]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/xH1fP3/1

It cuts out the `-` but leaves the `_` when in a string.

Comment: Thanks, but doesnt get the last part